# Pip Wheel and coverage: command not found error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip, python-wheel

I want to use wheels on my Linux server as it seems much faster, but when I do:

```
pip install wheel    
pip wheel -r requirements_dev.txt
```

Which contains the following packages

```
nose
django_coverage
coverage
```

I get **coverage: command not found**, it's like it is not being installed.

Is there a fallback if a wheel is not found to pip install or have I not understood/setup this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip -r install requirement.txt
```

Also getting this with using wheel:-

```
pip wheel -r check.txt
Collecting nose (from -r check.txt (line 1))
  Using cached nose-1.3.7-py2-none-any.whl
  Saved ./nose-1.3.7-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting django_coverage (from -r check.txt (line 2))
  Saved ./django_coverage-1.2.4-cp27-none-any.whl
Collecting coverage (from -r check.txt (line 3))
  Using cached coverage-4.2-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
  Saved ./coverage-4.2-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Skipping nose, due to already being wheel.
Skipping django-coverage, due to already being wheel.
Skipping coverage, due to already being wheel.
```

Comment: That works but not what I'm after i..e ``pip -r install requirement.txt``  I want to install from a wheel if available due to speed.

Comment: Down-voting this does not seem to be legit. Question clearly asks for a fallback.

Answer (score 1):

Installing from wheels is what pip already does by default. `pip wheel` is for *creating* wheels from your requirements file.

Comment: I see, ok that makes sense.